# What is the function of static attribute "category_ids" in "eav_attribute" table in 1.7?

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, magento-1.5

Try this query on Magento versions 1.5 and 1.7:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM  `eav_attribute` 
WHERE  `backend_type` LIKE  'static'
AND  `entity_type_id` =4
```

In 1.5, every row represents a field in the `catalog_product_entity` table:

```
created_at
has_options
required_options
sku
updated_at
```

But in 1.7, an additional attribute `category_ids` does not appear in `catalog_product_entity`.

What is it for? Why was it added?

Comment: can you please precise your question?
Do you need from which table or how to get category_ids?

Comment: @BijalBhavsar my question is about what is the function of an attribute found in the database table that does not appear in the backend.

Answer (score 5):

In old magento versions category->product information was stored in product attribute category_ids. The old api even contained filter to get product list by categories

```
$filters = array(
'category_ids' => array('like'=>'???')
);

$products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product.list', array($filters));
```

In new versions that behavior was changed. Now categories contain information about assigned products. You can see that in function Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product::getCategoryIds()

```
public function getCategoryIds($product)
{
    $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();

    $select = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->_productCategoryTable, 'category_id')
        ->where('product_id = ?', (int)$product->getId());

    return $adapter->fetchCol($select);
}
```

And during product collection load:
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addCategoryIds()

```
public function addCategoryIds()
{
    if ($this->getFlag('category_ids_added')) {
        return $this;
    }
    $ids = array_keys($this->_items);
    if (empty($ids)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $select = $this->getConnection()->select();

    $select->from($this->_productCategoryTable, array('product_id', 'category_id'));
    $select->where('product_id IN (?)', $ids);

    $data = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);

    $categoryIds = array();
    foreach ($data as $info) {
        if (isset($categoryIds[$info['product_id']])) {
            $categoryIds[$info['product_id']][] = $info['category_id'];
        } else {
            $categoryIds[$info['product_id']] = array($info['category_id']);
        }
    }


    foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
        $productId = $item->getId();
        if (isset($categoryIds[$productId])) {
            $item->setCategoryIds($categoryIds[$productId]);
        } else {
            $item->setCategoryIds(array());
        }
    }

    $this->setFlag('category_ids_added', true);
    return $this;
}
```

Why the attribute is still there I don't know. Maybe it was left for correct migration from old versions to new ones.

Comment: I don't have the attribute in a 1.5 installation, but I do in 1.7. I found a thread on the magento forum where people are complaining about its removal. Perhaps they reintroduced it to satisfy them.